# creating a new dataframe using boolean masks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing text in a column called `text` and the respective language in which the text is written stored in the column `lang`. What I am trying to do is create a secondary dataframe containing only the text wrritten in english(so has the value `en` in the `lang` column). The dataframe also contains other values so i can't just copy it. This is what I tried :

```
english_only = df['lang'] == 'en'
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df[english_only]['text'],columns = ['text','sentiment'])
```

When I run the code i get a dataframe of the same length as the original one but it only contains NaN values. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `DataFrame` constructor is not necessary, filter by mask for [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and by columns names in list by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), (solution working if `df` contains `sentiment` column):

```
df_2 = df.loc[english_only, ['text','sentiment']]
```

If want add `sentiment` column later:

```
df_2 = df.loc[english_only, ['text']]
```

Comment: the original doesn't have the ```sentiment``` column but I only took the text and will add that column later thanks

Comment: @LucaMarinescu - added solution for this situtation